# how to attach a three different sqlite3 databases D1,D2 and D3 to another Database D4 using bash or java

Tags: java, shell, sqlite

I have 3 different databases in the same folder as shown below

[image]

I want to attach other 3 databases to  `joined.db` database and then create a table named `join1`  as shown below

```
public class attaching_DB {


public static void main(String args[]) {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");


        String database_path = "/Users/amar/Documents/ThesisCode/CEP_Architectures/databases/joined.db";

        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + database_path);


        System.out.println("connection to sql is made");

        stmt = c.createStatement();




        // attaching all the tables in joined database
        String a1 = "ATTACH DATABASE 'mobile_data.db' as 'mobile';" ;
        String a2 = "ATTACH DATABASE 'server_data.db' as 'server';" ;
        String a3 = "ATTACH DATABASE 'flink_data.db' as 'flink';" ;


        stmt.execute(a1);
        stmt.execute(a2);
        stmt.execute(a3);


        String b1 =  "CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS  mobile_events as select * from mobile.mobile_events;"   ;
        String b2 =  "CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS  server_events  as select * from server.server_events;" ;
        String b3 =  "CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS  flink_events  as select * from flink.flink_events;"  ;

        stmt.executeUpdate(b1);
        stmt.executeUpdate(b2);
        stmt.executeUpdate(b3);


        // joining mobile and server data
        String join1 = "CREATE TABLE  if not EXISTS join1 as select M.patientid, M.sensorid , M.uid , M.egtl, M.egtg, S.eatg, M.valuez from mobile_events M inner join server_events S  on M.sensorid = S.sensorid and  M.uid = S.uid ; " ;
        stmt.executeUpdate(join1);



        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("attach is successful");
}
```

}

I am getting the following error

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: mobile.mobile_events)
```

The issue is that attach is not working, I tried to do the same using executable bash as shown below, but when `sqlite3 joined.db` is executed a new tab is opened and script stops

```
    #! /bin/bash
clear
cd /Users/amar/Documents/ThesisCode/CEP_Architectures/databases/
#starting sqlite3
sqlite3 joined.db

# attaching other db's
ATTACH DATABASE 'mobile_data.db' as 'mobile';
ATTACH DATABASE 'server_data.db' as 'server';
ATTACH DATABASE 'flink_data.db' as 'flink';

# creating tables
CREATE TABLE mobile_events as select * from mobile.mobile_events;
CREATE TABLE server_events as select * from server.server_events;
CREATE TABLE server_events as select * from server.server_events;

# crate a joined table
CREATE TABLE join1 as select M.patientid, M.sensorid , M.uid , M.egtl, M.egtg, S.eatg, M.valuez from mobile_events M inner join server_events S  on M.sensorid = S.sensorid and  M.uid = S.uid ;
echo "program is complete"
```

P.S: I am able to attach databases and create a table join1 by manually writing these scripts in terminal, but as I am doing some experimentation, so I don't want to do it again and again

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Why do you think Bash would execute `attach` and `create` commands natively?  Please post the COMPLETE stack trace and indicate which statement in your code throws the exception.

Comment: Also, it looks like you did not change the current directory in your Java program so you'd need to specify the absolute path in your `ATTACH DATABASE` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing SQL statements to bash, which doesn't understand them.  Pass them to sqlite3 instead, like:

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
cd /Users/amar/Documents/ThesisCode/CEP_Architectures/databases/
#starting sqlite3
sqlite3 joined.db <<EOF

-- attaching other db's
ATTACH DATABASE "mobile_data.db" as mobile;
ATTACH DATABASE "server_data.db" as server;
ATTACH DATABASE "flink_data.db" as flink;

-- creating tables
CREATE TABLE mobile_events as select * from mobile.mobile_events;
CREATE TABLE server_events as select * from server.server_events;
CREATE TABLE flink_events as select * from flink.flink_events;

-- create a joined table
CREATE TABLE join1 as select M.patientid, M.sensorid , M.uid , M.egtl, M.egtg, S.eatg, M.valuez from mobile_events M inner join server_events S  on M.sensorid = S.sensorid and  M.uid = S.uid ;

EOF

echo "program is complete"
```

Comment: I'm sure your solution works, but you're creating the 'server_events' table twice... I'm guessing you copied original SQL and meant to edit for 'flink_events'?

Comment: @openwonk:  You're right - I just reworked the original code and didn't notice the duplication.  I'll modify my answer accordingly.  Thanks for noticing.